# Isolate iframes sessions

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have 6 iframes that are from the same domain but with different url and subdirectory. They all set a cookie that has the same name but different value using html header "set-cookie". I need to separate their cookies so that they don't interfere with each other.

Here is an example code. Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, table
        {
            margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; scrolling=no; position:absolute;;
        }
        iframe
        {
            height: 100%; width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<table>

    <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>
                <iframe id="1" src="http://example.com/1"></iframe>
                   </td>
                <td>
                <iframe id="2" src="http://example.com/2"></iframe>
                    </td>
                <td>
                <iframe id="3" src="http://example.com/3"></iframe>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <iframe id="4" src="http://example.com/4"></iframe>
                    </td>
                <td>
                <iframe id="5" src="http://example.com/5"></iframe>
                    </td>
                <td>
                <iframe id="6" src=http://example.com/6></iframe
            </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
```

> Note that I don't have access to the server/domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies include [a path attribute](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.4):

> If the attribute-name case-insensitively matches the string "Path",
> the user agent MUST process the cookie-av as follows.
>
> If the attribute-value is empty or if the first character of the
> attribute-value is not %x2F ("/"):
>
> *Let cookie-path be the default-path.*
>
> Otherwise:
>
> *Let cookie-path be the attribute-value.*
>
> Append an attribute to the cookie-attribute-list with an attribute-
> name of Path and an attribute-value of cookie-path.

Cookies are [only sent if the cookie path matches the URL path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.4).

Configure your server so that it provides a different path for each of the 6 things in the frames.

Comment: Note that I don't have access to the server/domain.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your use case? Because it sounds a bit strange to me... But, easy does it; just namespace your cookies!

```
document.cookie = 'frameOne=foo';
document.cookie = 'frameTwo=bar';
```

And access the needed cookie in the specific frame.

And as @Quentin mentioned; do *not* suspect this is safe at all. If you wish to separate authentication, use different domains, multi-login system, or whatever. However; it does seem odd to me that you want one user to login 6 times.

Comment: Note that I don't have access to the server/domain.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more what you are doing exactly? What kind of pages are you bringing in? As if you do not have access to the domain, you shouldn't be able to read the cookies...

Comment: I try to watch many videos simultaneosly but every video gets a cookie and I want them to be separated for every iframe...

Comment: Ok, so far so good, but why do you need the cookies anyway? What is wrong with just embedding the videos, be it in an iframe or in a `<video>` html5 element? Do you embed the video's from your own server? Or from a service like youtube or vimeo?

Comment: Bottom lime: your question is sooooo generic that we cannot help you in finding a specific solution...